# How do I differentiate a Kronecker product with respect to a vector?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to differentiate $[\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^*\mathbf{t}^T]$ with respect to $\mathbf{t}$. I did the following

$\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^*\mathbf{t}^T = (\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^*) (\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^T)$.

Apply chain rule.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{t}} (\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^*\mathbf{t}^T) =  (\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^*) \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{t}}(\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^T) + (\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^T) \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{t}} (\mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{t}^*)$.

What do I do next?

$*$ represents conjugate. $T$ represents transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:t\in \mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow I\otimes t^*t^T$. Then the derivative is $Df_t:h\in\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow I\otimes (h^*t^T+t^*h^T)$.

EDIT. Answer to hughhouse. No, the derivative is the linear function s.t. $f(t+h)=f(t)+Df_t(h)+o(||h||)=I\otimes (t^*t^T+h^*t^T+t^*h^T+o(||h||))$.

Comment: Is $h = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$?